# ffplay -noborder option missing argument

Tags: ffmpeg

If I do:

```
ffplay -i vid.mp4
```

ffplay works fine, however if I try the borderless option:

```
ffplay -noborder -i vid.mp4

Failed to set value '-i' for option 'noborder': Option not found
```

Trying the -noborder option at the end of the command:

```
ffplay -i vid.mp4 -noborder

Missing argument for option 'noborder'
```

Any clue on the argument -noborder is waiting for or why isn't this working?

This is the ffplay version I am using:

```
ffplay version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
```

Comment: Try with an upgraded version of ffplay. According to [this](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) there are 6 release branches greater than 2.8 (3.2, 3.4, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-noborder` was added in 2017, but the FFmpeg 2.8 release branch is from 2015. You need FFmpeg 3.4 or newer for `-noborder`.

You can follow step-by-step [compile instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) that you can copy and paste.